# Use d3 log scale instead of linear scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hierarchy, bar-chart

I'm trying to do a chart based on http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/bar-hierarchy.html, the only difference being that I'd like to use a log scale for the x-axis.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JhDVC/5/

As you can see, the x-axis is defined at line 4:

```
x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
```

If I change it for

```
x = d3.scale.log().range([0, w]),
```

Then it doesn't work (nothing is rendered), throwing these error messages:

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute width="NaN"
```

Changing the domain setting from

```
x.domain([0, root.value]).nice();
```

to

```
x.domain([1, root.value]).nice();
```

shows me the z axis (names) but still no bars or values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few other places where the domain for the scale is set. You need to update those as well.

Working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JhDVC/7/).

And here's some code so that it allows me to post this:

```
x.domain([1, root.value]).nice();
```

Answer (score 7):

Your range includes zero - log(0) is undefined.

Comment: … simple to forget when just trying to switch a linear axis scale to logarithmic 